convenient way to select columns within a function based on regex within dplyr
I am trying to select columns based on a regex for a function within a dplyr command.
Maybe I am thinking to complicated or I have to reframe my data first?
I provide a reproducible example. I would love to define the columns to use inside length with a regular expression. So in my case col_of_interest are all the columns with a inside...
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
col_of_interest <- 'a'
df <- 
  data.frame(
    id=rep(1:2, each=5),
    a1=rnorm(10),
    a2=c(NA, NA, NA, rnorm(7)),
    b1=rnorm(10)
  )

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  reframe(value_count=length(na.omit(c(a1, a2))))


I'd just generalize the use of matches() a bit with pick() to work with a tidy-selected subset. Your current approach might look like:
library(dplyr)
col_of_interest <- 'a'

df %>% 
  reframe(
    value_count = 
      pick(matches(col_of_interest)) %>% do.call(what = c) %>% na.omit() %>% length()
    , .by = id
  )
#>   id value_count
#> 1  1           7
#> 2  2          10

Or perhaps:
df %>%
  reframe(
    value_count = 
      pick(matches(col_of_interest)) %>% {!is.na(.)} %>% sum()
    , .by = id
  )
#>   id value_count
#> 1  1           7
#> 2  2          10


pick is something I was dreaming of... This helps a lot!

Maybe pivoting longer might help:
> set.seed(1)
> df0 = data.frame(id=rep(1:2, each=5), a1=rnorm(10), a2=c(NA, NA, NA, rnorm(7)), b1=rnorm(10))
> 
> {
+   library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
+   library(tidyr)
+ }
> 
> df0 |>
+   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("a")) |>
+   reframe(value_count = length(na.omit(value)), .by = id)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     id value_count
  <int>       <int>
1     1           7
2     2          10

where you want to replace starts_with("a") according to your logic.

You need c_across:
## no need to use reframe as we are returning anyways just a single value

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(value_count = length(na.omit(c_across(matches(col_of_interest)))))

#   id value_count
# 1  1           7
# 2  2          10


This was just my minimal example, in my original task I needed the reframe... I looked up the description for c_across and it mentioned it is designed for row_wise usage... Not sure if I would misuse it the way you showed me. Thanks! It is already a big help!

Well, rowwise is one (prominent) use case, but under the hood it is c with  tidy select semantics. So IMHO whereever you would legitimately use c you can drop in c_across to get tidy select syntax.
